# Installing Ub 13.04 and Win 7 boot loader issues

Tags: 13.04, boot, windows

I have a computer with a Vertex 3 SSD which I have Windows 7 64 Hp installed on. I also have a second Maxtor HDD which I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 onto today. Because I was afraid of mucking up my other HDDs when I was formatting for Ubuntu I removed them from my computer, just leaving the Maxtor which I installed Ubuntu on. Now when I have all the drives installed and boot the computer it just loads Windows, wit no option for Ubuntu or Windows. I know you're meant to install Ubuntu after Windows, but with no Windows OS plugged in while I installed Ubuntu I think it only sees itself when I boot my computer.
I want a way to pick the OS at start up.
If anyone can make sense of what I've just said  and can help that would be great!

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You have to in BIOS choose to boot the drive with Ubuntu. That should have grub2's boot loader installed in the MBR.

Then after booting Ubuntu run this to get os-prober to find all your other installs. When you installed it did not find the other installs since drives were not connected.

```
sudo update-grub
```